# I have a text file containing digits separated by commas, and i need to read it and store its row by rows into an array

Tags: arrays, matlab

The last digit of every row indicates the class.I need to save each row into an array and thereby check the last digit of each row. How can i do this with MATLAB.

Comment: Please show your effort. I will give you a hint. This can be done by `textscan` or `dlmread`.

Comment: I got a code to store columns into array,                           f = textscan('file1.txt', '%c');
vals = reshape(f, 7, []);
oneColumn = vals(:,1);  but i need to store it in row vice
otherStuff = vals(:,2:end);